# Error funcion Rand() usando Struct en c++

Tags: c++

Quiero hacer un programa que me calcule la distancia entre dos puntos mediante un struct. La formula es: √(x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1). Y si ejecuto el programa que tengo, no me genera correctamente los valores en la estructura. Si alguno sabe mi error que me lo comente porfavor. Os dejo aquí el código que llevo hecho:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
struct Punto{
    int x;
    int y; 
};

void rellenar(Punto p1, Punto p2){
    p1.x=(int)(rand()%50);
    p2.y=rand()%50;
    p2.x=rand()%50;
    p2.y=rand()%50;
}

void mostrar(Punto p1,Punto p2){
    cout<<"La coordenada p1.x ->"<<p1.x<<endl;
    cout<<"La coordenada p1.y ->"<<p1.y<<endl;
    cout<<"La coordenada p2.x ->"<<p2.x<<endl;
    cout<<"La coordenada p2.y ->"<<p2.y<<endl;
}

float distancia(Punto p1,Punto p2){
    float distancia;    
    distancia=sqrt(pow(p2.x -p1.x,2)+pow(p2.y-p1.y,2));
    return distancia;
}

int main(){
    Punto p1,p2;
    srand(time(NULL));
    rellenar(p1,p2);
    mostrar(p1,p2);
    cout<<"La distancia entre el punto 1 y 2 es: "<<distancia(p1,p2)<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En C++ a las funciones, los valores por default se pasan por copia. A la funcion: `void rellenar(Punto p1, Punto p2)` le estas pasando copias de los valores, no los valores originales.

Lo que tienes que hacer es recivir referencias a los valores, y cuando no modifiques los valores, para evitar copias, pasas por referencia constante.

Aqui tienes un [QA en isocpp.org](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
struct Punto{
    int x;
    int y; 
};

void rellenar(Punto& p1, Punto& p2){
    p1.x=(int)(rand()%50);
    p2.y=rand()%50;
    p2.x=rand()%50;
    p2.y=rand()%50;
}

void mostrar(const Punto& p1, const Punto& p2){
    cout<<"La coordenada p1.x ->"<<p1.x<<endl;
    cout<<"La coordenada p1.y ->"<<p1.y<<endl;
    cout<<"La coordenada p2.x ->"<<p2.x<<endl;
    cout<<"La coordenada p2.y ->"<<p2.y<<endl;
}

float distancia(const Punto& p1, const Punto& p2){
    float distancia;    
    distancia=sqrt(pow(p2.x -p1.x,2)+pow(p2.y-p1.y,2));
    return distancia;
}

int main(){
    Punto p1,p2;
    srand(time(NULL));
    rellenar(p1,p2);
    mostrar(p1,p2);
    cout<<"La distancia entre el punto 1 y 2 es: "<<distancia(p1,p2)<<endl;
}
```

Aunque en este caso los que son por referencia constante no importan tanto, solo copias 2 enteros. Pero sera importante si por ejemplo pasas un vector, o un string.